# 95% chance of 1.6 Standard deviation?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I'M reading a book on portfolio management and I can't understand how the author came up with 95% chance of volatility reaching 1.6 times..here's the excerpt:
"Suppose that we were to forecast that equity volatility over the next five years(our investment horizon) would average 20 percent a year (the long-term average or close to it). An equity exposure of 60 percent in our portfolio would translate this to a 12 percent volatility (0.60 times 20 percent) from the equity risk factor. This means an approximately 5 percent chance, of a drawdown of 1.6 times the volatility, that is, a 1 in 20 chance of a drawdown of more than 19.2 percent."

From what I remember from stats,in a normal distribution,95% equates to 2 STD and not 1.6.  Shouldn't the 19.2% drawdown be 24%?

Answer (score 5):

A two-sided interval from -2 to +2 standard deviations of a normal distribution covers roughly 95% of the distribution. In the quoted passage, we are only concerned about movement in the downward direction, corresponding to a one-sided interval. A one-sided interval covering all values greater than -1.6 standard deviations captures roughly 95% of the distribution.

Comment: I don't think the question concerns confidence intervals.  It is merely making a statement about probabilities based on given values of the parameters of a Normal distribution.

Comment: I rewrote a bit